# An easy question on number theory

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Is there any positive integer $k>1$ such that $p^k-1$ be a power of 2, that is $p^k-1=2^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: $3^2 - 1 = 2^3$??

Comment: @ex0du5 I think $p$ is fixed here...

Comment: @exodu5: Is there any more?

Comment: A remark: Since $p-1$ divides $p^k-1$, it's only possible if $p-1$ is a power of $2$. The known primes of that form are $3$, $5$, $17$, $257$, and $65535$; we don't know if there are any others (probably not).

Comment: The hard way to do this is to note that it's a special case of Catalan's conjecture, that 8 and 9 are the only consecutive pair of perfect powers, which is now Mihailescu's Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in de comments, $p-1$ has to be a power of $2$. Let us write $p = 2^t + 1$. We now have
$$
p^k - 1 = (2^t+1)^k - 1 = \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i} 2^{ti} \equiv k \cdot 2^t \mod 2^{2t}.
$$
Since $p^k - 1 > 2^t$ for $k > 1$, this implies that $k$ is even. Now $p^k - 1$ factors as $(p^{k/2} - 1)(p^{k/2}+1)$ and both $p^{k/2} - 1$ and $p^{k/2}+1$ should be powers of $2$. This is only possible for $p^{k/2} = 3$, or $p=3$ and $k=2$. The solution given by exodu5, therefore, is unique.